# Ribbon TextChange Event

Tags: vb.net, ribbon

I'm creating an Excel add-in. I have a `TextBox` on the Ribbon named **Keyword**.

I want to populate another `TextBox` named **Category** based on the value in the **Keyword** `TextBox`.

I want the **Category** `TextBox` to refresh each time the user types a new character into the **Keyword** `TextBox`.

The problem is that the Office Ribbon `TextBox` has only one event, which is `TextChanged`. This event gets fired only after the `TextBox` has lost focus.

How can I create an event which would get fired each time the user types a character in the `TextBox`?

This is the code of TextChange event. It works correctly. I only need to run it after each keystroke and not only after the text box has loosed focus:

```
Private Sub txtEnterKeyword_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles txtEnterKeyword.TextChanged
    Dim myDict As New Dictionary(Of String, Long)
    Dim maxNr As Long, maxStr As String = ""
    Dim txt As String

    If GetRegistrySetting("OfferColumn") = 0 Then Exit Sub

    txt = Trim(LCase(sender.Text))
    If txt Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    If dictHelper.ContainsKey(txt) Then
        myDict = dictHelper(txt)
        For Each key In myDict.Keys()
            If maxNr < myDict(key) Then
                maxNr = myDict(key)
                maxStr = key
            End If
        Next
    End If

    If maxStr <> "" Then
        cmbSelectColumn.Text = maxStr
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You might want to include the relevant code that supports your question.

Comment: I added the code of the TextChange event. Something else needed?